# Unable to get SelectedIndex value after Items.Clear in ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Every 5 seconds bind new data to listbox, before binding i will clear the existing data in the Listbox using Items.Clear().After clearing the items im not able to get SelectedItem text from the listbox.

> 1) Load Data not on Before PostBack, Load Data every PostBack.....

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                   //Not Loading Data on !IsPostBack condition, Every 5 seconds it will get new data.
                }
                    LoadAciveEmployees();
    }

    2) Bind Values To ListBox

    protected void LoadAciveEmployees()
    {
            DataTable dataContainer = (getting Data from sqlserver)  

            lbxActiveEmp.Items.Clear();
            lbxActiveEmp.DataTextField = "Name";
            lbxActiveEmp.DataValueField = "EmpID";

            foreach (DataRow dr in dataContainer.Rows)
            {
                string empID = dr["EmpID"].ToString();
                string name = dr["Name"].ToString();
                lbxActiveEmp.Items.Add(new ListItem(name + " - " + empID, empID));
            }

    }

3) Get Selected Value from listtbox,

    protected void getValue()
    {
        if (lbxActiveEmp.SelectedIndex != -1) //Based on this condition get selected value
        {
                    selectedUser = lbxActiveEmp.SelectedItem.Text.ToString(); ***
        }

    }

*** -- After clearing the items, how get SelectedItem (text or value), Is it possible to get selected item text after items are cleared?
Please help me out from this issue.
```

Comment: first of all put the "LoadAciveEmployees();" inside the PostBack

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Then how can i bind data every 5 seconds,that's why i have mentioned outside the postback

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to get selected item text after items are cleared?

**No**, You can not get *selected* item after clearing. This is quite abvious behaviour as how we can get the item that does not exists in the collection. The `Clear` method makes the item collection empty. You can save the item unique attribute like item id before clearing and use that later.

Comment: After Clearing items, again binding the new data to the Listbox so it possible to get Selected value, but it's not showing the selected item value???

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var lbxActiveEmp = new ListBox(); // create new instance instead of using Clear();
lbxActiveEmp.DataTextField = "Name";
lbxActiveEmp.DataValueField = "EmpID";
```